# How React Can Change Components With Key Attribute?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

My Root Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Task from "./components/task";

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        keys: [0, 1]
    }

    changeKeysHandler = () => {
        const { keys } = this.state;
        const newKeys = keys.slice().reverse();
        this.setState({
            keys: newKeys
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Task key={this.state.keys[0]}/>
                <Task key={this.state.keys[1]}/>
                <button onClick={this.changeKeysHandler}>Reverse</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

My Task Component

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function Task() {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState("Tofiq")
    return(
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={value}
                onChange={(event) => { setValue(event.target.value) }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I change keys React Components change orders. But I don't understand what is happening under the hood. How React key attributes related with components. Can you explain the implantation of this to me?

Comment: I advise you to read this article. 
https://tr.reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html.
You can use a different name.

Comment: @Minan I read it but my question is little bit different. I don't try to get key property from child. İ try to update my component via key property but İ don't understand how React save references with key property. Just check my question again :)

Answer (score 3):

A `key` is the only thing React uses to identify `DOM` elements.

> To understand the working of `key`, let's understand React behavior without `key` first.

Let's say we have a list

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

By default, when recursing on the children of a `DOM` node, React just iterates over both lists of children at the same time and generates a mutation whenever there’s a difference.

For example, when adding an element at the end of the children, converting between these two trees works well:

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

`React` will match the two `<li>first</li>` trees, match the two `<li>second</li>` trees, and then insert the `<li>third</li>` tree.

Insert an element at the `beginning` has worse performance. For example, converting between these two trees works poorly, and React will mutate every child instead of realizing it can keep the `<li>Duke</li>` and `<li>Villanova</li>` subtrees intact. This inefficiency can be a problem.

#### Keys

In order to solve this issue, React supports a `key` attribute. When children have `keys`, React uses the `key` to match children in the original tree with children in the subsequent tree.

For example, adding a `key` to our inefficient example above can make the tree conversion efficient:

```
<ul>
  <li key="2015">Duke</li>
  <li key="2016">Villanova</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li key="2014">Connecticut</li>
  <li key="2015">Duke</li>
  <li key="2016">Villanova</li>
</ul>
```

Now React knows that the element with key `'2014'` is the new one, and the elements with the keys `'2015'` and `'2016'` have just moved.

> **Now let's talk about your problem**

React's `key` prop gives you the ability to control component instances. Each time React renders your components, it's calling your functions to retrieve the new React elements that it uses to update the `DOM`. If you return the same element types, it keeps those `components/DOM` nodes around, even if all* the props changed.

In your case component instances are updated and reused based on their key. On changing the `key` of the list, the component state for things like uncontrolled inputs can get mixed up and updated in unexpected ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my example you can saw my input element not uncontrolled but controlled. Is this mean React keys store component reference itself? And new VirtualDOM elements create by this key's related elements?

Comment: According to React doc, Component instances are updated and reused based on their key. In your case component state mixed up like uncontrolled Input as values are not controlled by the parent component. Try passing `value` as a prop in `<Task>` Component. It won't give you an unexpected results.

Comment: You can find similar problem here : https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/reconciliation/index-used-as-key, where `similar id` as `key` assigned to new element which causing the issue.

and `solution` https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/reconciliation/no-index-used-as-key,  where `unique id` is passed on every `new element insertion`.

Comment: Yeah I read it and I  know how fix this. But I try to understand implementation detail of this. For example I understand somehow React keys save component instances  but how about React Function components. I think there are not have any instances like class components. But in my example how React know which state related which component and when key change component state also changed

Comment: While `diffing`, it starts comparing elements in it with the ones in the array it saw before by looking at them in order: index 0 will be compared to index 0, index 1 to index 1, etc. For each pair, React will apply the set of rules. This is very time consuming task.

Luckily, React has a built-in way to solve this problem. If an element has a key property, elements will be compared by a value of a key, not by index. As long as keys are unique, React will move elements around without removing them from DOM tree and then putting them back (a process known in React as mounting/unmounting).

Comment: That's why, since you haven't introduced new unique key, React just moved the component instead of removing and checking changes and then putting them back.

Comment: Hi @harish kumar, I'm liking your explanation, so as long as they are the same keys React will only move the elements, until a key is inserted or deleted is that when it mounts/dismounts or just mounts (in case of insert)?